# Memory management - how memblock_reserve works

Tags: linux, memory

I am working on Marvel PXA986 boards and in board file I can see few memory reservation code using `memblock_reserve`. But immediately after `memblock_reserve`, I can see the `memblock_free` and `memblock_remove` getting called. When we reserve memory what's the point removing it immediately?

Can anyone throw some light upon memblock API's?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not absolutely sure if I understand the question, but maybe this is at least a pointer to right direction. As about the API, I don't think there isn't much else to be done about that but to read the source.

This is going to be nothing but a prose version of what source says. The version which I consulted was 3.11.7.

From shuffling through quickly the relevant bits if `mm/memblock.c` it seems that 1) memblock_reserve() calls memblock_add_region() which under certain conditions calls memblock_double_array() which may then call, again under certain conditions, memblock_free(). This happens when the kernel has found free space and has to move the array pointing to actual memory regions as the old array in case the array is full already (see lines 267-278 of `mm/memblock.c`).

So to sum it up: it's not necessary an error condition if you see memblock_free() and memblock_remove() getting called immediately after memblock_reserve(), I think.